# Caching the downloaded data

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uicollectionview

I am using collection View to display the product data in each cell. Each time when user refreshes `collectionview`, it fetches data from the server again.

I need to know is there a caching mechanism available which caches downloaded images. I want to download only recently updated products which are not cached.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myURL/productAll.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSError *myError = nil;
    id res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];        
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[res count]; i++) {
        NSString *arrayResult = [[res objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"image"];            
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:arrayResult options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
        UIImage *captcha_image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [items addObject:captcha_image];
    }
    [collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: Try using `NSURLCache`

Comment: could you please illustrate with an example if you could?

Comment: see my answer below, just a quick example (not tested) but I use  something like this in several apps

Comment: I have seen your code, thanks a lot. I wonder how do you know which product has been cached? I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Have a look at `
- cachedResponseForRequest:`

Answer (score 1):

Use NSURLCache to setup memory and disk cache like this:

```
int cacheSizeMemory = xxxxx; //in memory cache
int cacheSizeDisk = xxxxx; //disk cache
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```